# Similate double click on drag end - jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, chap-links-library

Here I have a table with two column. In 1st is draggable div object so:

```
$(function() {
    $( "div.available" ).draggable({
              snap: "div.timeline-axis-grid"
    });
  });
```

and in 2nd column is timeline table based on google visualisation API.
http://jsbin.com/oLaqoToH/5

You will see when make double click on timeline table then you create a new div object into timeline.

Now I want to simulate double click when I end dragging object from 1st column to timeline.
So simple I want to add a div object from 1st column to timeline with this little hack.
Is there any way to do this?
Is this possbile to use with jquery?
How I can simulate dobuleclick on draggable ending?

**UPDATE:**  I dont need to simulate double clikc becouse this action has an function:

http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/timeline.js

```
/**
 * Double click event occurred for an item
 * @param {Event}  event
 */
links.Timeline.prototype.onDblClick = function (event) {
    var params = this.eventParams,
        options = this.options,
        dom = this.dom,
        size = this.size;
    event = event || window.event;

    if (params.itemIndex != undefined) {
        var item = this.items[params.itemIndex];
        if (item && this.isEditable(item)) {
            // fire the edit event
            this.trigger('edit');
        }
    }
    else {
        if (options.editable) {
            // create a new item

            // get mouse position
            params.mouseX = links.Timeline.getPageX(event);
            params.mouseY = links.Timeline.getPageY(event);
            var x = params.mouseX - links.Timeline.getAbsoluteLeft(dom.content);
            var y = params.mouseY - links.Timeline.getAbsoluteTop(dom.content);

            // create a new event at the current mouse position
            var xstart = this.screenToTime(x);
            var xend = this.screenToTime(x  + size.frameWidth / 10); // add 10% of timeline width
            if (options.snapEvents) {
                this.step.snap(xstart);
                this.step.snap(xend);
            }

            var content = options.NEW;
            var group = this.getGroupFromHeight(y);   // (group may be undefined)
            var preventRender = true;
            this.addItem({
                'start': xstart,
                'end': xend,
                'content': content,
                'group': this.getGroupName(group)
            }, preventRender);
            params.itemIndex = (this.items.length - 1);
            this.selectItem(params.itemIndex);

            this.applyAdd = true;

            // fire an add event.
            // Note that the change can be canceled from within an event listener if
            // this listener calls the method cancelAdd().
            this.trigger('add');

            if (this.applyAdd) {
                // render and select the item
                this.render({animate: false});
                this.selectItem(params.itemIndex);
            }
            else {
                // undo an add
                this.deleteItem(params.itemIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    links.Timeline.preventDefault(event);
};
```

How I can use this function to drag object to timeline instead to use doubleclick simulation??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "div.available" ).draggable({
    snap: "div.timeline-axis-grid",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).dblclick();
    }
});
```

Comment: also how I can call double click but not on coursoe coordinates but on draggable div object top and left ???

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    $( "div.timeline-event" ).draggable({
          snap: "div.timeline-axis-grid",
          stop: function(event){ timeline.onDblClick(event); }
    });
});
```

Comment: also how I can call double click but not on coursoe coordinates but on draggable div object top and left ???